# Project Reactor: Schedulers#parallel & Schedulers#elastic purpose

Tags: java, multithreading, project-reactor

I am learning [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) where I am exploring `Schedulers factory`.

I tried the following code:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Flux.range(1,4)
                    .map(i -> {
                        logger.info(i +" [MAP] " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        return 10 / i;
                    })
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.fromExecutorService(executorService)) // .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
                    .subscribe(
                            n -> {
                                logger.info("START "+((Long)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000000L)).toString());
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                logger.info(n.toString());
                                logger.info("END "+((Long)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 10000000L)).toString());
                            }
                    );
        executorService.shutdown();
```

This code was tried with [Schedulers.parallel()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#parallel--) and [Schedulers.elastic()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#elastic--) as well. Also, tried with `subscribeOn()` operator to see similar results.

The logs are:

```
02:07:30.142 [main] INFO  - 1 [MAP] main
02:07:30.143 [main] INFO  - 2 [MAP] main
02:07:30.143 [main] INFO  - 3 [MAP] main
02:07:30.143 [main] INFO  - 4 [MAP] main
02:07:30.143 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - START 1050143
02:07:30.247 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - 10
02:07:30.247 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - END 1050247
02:07:30.247 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - START 1050247
02:07:30.350 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - 5
02:07:30.350 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - END 1050350
02:07:30.350 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - START 1050350
02:07:30.455 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - 3
02:07:30.455 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - END 1050455
02:07:30.455 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - START 1050455
02:07:30.557 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - 2
02:07:30.558 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  - END 1050558
```

Since the `Flux`'s elements are ordered and operated upon in sequence (apparent from the logs above), having multiple threads for an `operator` (or `operator chain`) for one element does not make sense. I am sure I am either misinterpreting the `Schedulers` or lack somewhere in my basic understanding. Can someone point me to the right direction?

I understand the purpose of `Schedulers` to make the processing `asynchronous` and unhold the `main` thread. But why would anyone want to give multiple threads to the `operator(s)` when operated at one element at a time.

Does it makes sense only when we deal with `flatMap` `operator`?

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the `.map` and the `.publishOn` operators?

Comment: You answered your question in the last sentence. Some operators introduce concurrency. Usually you don't create a scheduler for every stream, but share it across streams, so it doesn't matter that much how many threads one stream will use.